# Understanding EJB in the context of web applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

I have been working with J2E web applications for some years now and have started to use EJB over the last few weeks.
I created a project based on this example

1. Basically I create two maven projects, similar to what is described here https://blog.illucit.com/2015/04/ejb-remoting-with-wildfly/,  one that builds a web application(war) and one that builds an EJB.
   In web applications pom I add a dependency to my EJB and I can use a context look up to call the correct EJB and cast it to the correct class type. Even though my bean is annotated with remote I am guessing this is a local invocation.
2. On a second attempt I deployed an EJB module and separably deployed the web application. I was able to do a context look up to pull in the session bean. But I could only cast it to an Object class. I think because I had no reference to the EJB in my web application, as it was part of a separably deployed module, I couldn't do the cast.

   I would imagine that since my web applications are seperate, this is a very simple example of a distributed system?
   If so, How do I avoid this casting issue, if the class definition is in another application?

Edit-
Because I havent got the awnser I was looking for I have tried to narrow the scope of my question some more.

On this example
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance

You can see the client is able to call the Greeter class, even though it is sitting on another server. The client has no import of the Greeter class.
So how is it able to cast the EJB lookup to a class it doesn't have any reference to?

Comment: This might help: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI?_sscc=t

Comment: Show us your code, please. From the sound of things, this may be working as intended. There are two methods for obtaining a reference to an EJB: resource lookup and dependency injection by a container.  The former is not type safe and requires an explicit cast, the latter is type safe and requies no cast.

Comment: The blog post you've linked to describes how to "call some methods on the EJBs from _outside the application server_" (emphasis mine). In the deployment you've described, everything is deployed to the same application server, and you should be able to use simple annotation-based injection. You have greatly and unnecessarily complicated your use of EJBs, I think.

Comment: Tip: the last version of "Java 2 Platform, Enterprise Edition" (J2EE) was released in 2003. Subsequent platforms have been called "Java Platform, Enterprise Edition" (Java EE) ever since. You can continue calling it J2EE if you'd like, but I wouldn't recommend putting it on a resume. (Thanks @BalusC)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to divide the EJB and the WAR project in different servers you need a third project (normal Java project) with all the objects (POJO, VO, DTO or Entities) that you will use for communicate between WAR and EJB and also you need to put all EJB's Remote interfaces. In this way you can do the "cast". This new project must be a dependency of both projects EJB and WAR.